# local storage object value retrieving issue in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am getting `undefined` when retrieving `user.firstName`. Please let me know what is wrong here. Thank you.

```
class UserBlock extends Component {
 render() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    return (
      <div>{user.firstName}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to get `user` object in console as below:

```
{ id: 1, username: 'admin', password: 'admin', firstName: 'Admin', lastName: 'User', role: 'Admin' }
```

Comment: can you post what your `user` const returns if you log it out? and the bit where you set it in localStorage as well

Comment: when I am printing user am able to get full object { id: 1, username: 'admin', password: 'admin', firstName: 'Admin', lastName: 'User', role: Admin }

Comment: can you show the code for how do you store the user in localstorage ?

Comment: It looks like race condition: the component is rendered earlier than (authorized) user is saved to the local storage. Consider to create minimal example that will reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following

```
class UserBlock extends Component {
 constructor(){
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  this.state = {
      user
  };
 }
 render() {
    const { user } = this.state
    return (
      <div>{user.firstName}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the componentDidMount() lifecycle function, it gets stuff done before the browser upudates the screen. (even async calls). read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  this.setState({user: user})
}

render() {
  const { user } = this.state
   return (
    <div>{user.firstName}</div>
   );
 }
}
```